# Linux BusyBox files

Tags: linux, connection, busybox

Do someone know which is the file (and where is it located) that is executed when BusyBox is turned on ?

Also, which is the file (and again, where is it located) that is executed when you connect to it from other PC ? [For example, if I tipe IP Address in Google Chrome, which is the HTML file that is shown?]

Comment: more information needed.  what device is running busybox?  how did you install it?  see https://busybox.net/FAQ.html

Comment: It is a EMTEC Movie Cube device, which i dont use so i'm trying to use it as multimedia server. This is BusyBox version:
BusyBox v1.1.3 (2008.12.25-02:18+0000) Built-in shell (ash)

Comment: If you're logged in to the system, then `which busybox` would give you he answer.  Typically it's /bin/busybox.